# Strange output while using strsep and fwrite in C

Tags: c, string, file, fwrite, strsep

I was going to make a python program to read from an XML document and use it as a reference while doing an action. However, the XML document would have been tedious to create by hand, so I decided to make a C program to do the bulk of it, excluding the first line and the root element. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    FILE * fp = fopen("/Users/rajshrimali/Desktop/SPC_CMS.txt", "r");
    FILE * fw = fopen("/Users/rajshrimali/Desktop/SPC_XML", "a");
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linecap = 0;
    ssize_t linelen;
    while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, fp)) > 0){
        char *token;
        int x = 1; 
        while((token = strsep(&line, ",")) != NULL){
            printf("%s", token);
            if(x == 1){
                fwrite("<item> \n", linelen, 1, fw);
                fwrite("<name> \n", linelen, 1, fw);
                fwrite(token, linelen, 1, fw);
                fwrite("\n </name> \n", linelen, 1, fw);
                x++; 
            }
            if(x == 2) {
                fwrite("<SPC> \n", linelen, 1, fw);
                fwrite(token, linelen, 1, fw);
                fwrite("\n </SPC> \n", linelen, 1, fw);
                fwrite("</item> \n", linelen, 1, fw);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiled with no errors. However, when I ran it, the file SPC_XML was not nearly right:

```
<item> 
�<na<name> 

 <Agate�0.80

 </name> 
�<SPC> 

 </Agate�0.80

 </SPC> 
<</item> 
,�<item> 
<na<name>
```

This nonsense continued for some time. 
The input file, `fp`, had data in this format:

```
Agate,0.80
Aluminum bronze,0.436
Aluminum,0.87
Antimony,0.21
Apatite,0.84
```

I *think* the error is with fwrite, although I have no idea what it is. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `fwrite`, the second argument should be the length of the string that you are writing. So, when you do:

```
fwrite("<item> \n", linelen, 1, fw);
```

you will end up writing extra data, or maybe not enough, depending on what `linelen` is. Instead, you should manually count the size of your strings or call `strlen` on each of them. So, the call above could be turned into:

```
fwrite("<item> \n", 8, 1, fw);
```

and when you write out the tokens, you should call `strlen`:

```
fwrite(token, strlen(token), 1, fw);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some obvious errors with your `if` statements here, you are using `=` assignment when you should be using `==` equality, for example:

```
 if(x = 1)
```

should be:

```
if(x == 1)
```

I would suggest turning on warning, using gcc with `-Wall -W -pedantic` you will see something like this:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
         if(x = 1){
```

Comment: I fixed that, same problem.

Comment: ..depending of compiler you are using,turn power on the compiler-warnings. It's very very useful. :)